# stripe.confirmCardPayment is not a function

Tags: node.js, subscription, recurring-billing, stripe-payments

when i am creating subscription through stripe it gives err message
As i am doing subscription through stripe
i am also giving some msg about authentication in dashboard like 3d secure authenticatio.
and my cvc_check is unavailable in showing dashboard
1.first issue is 3d secure authentication.
2.cvc check unavailbel in India.
My account is also india

```
TypeError: stripe.confirmCardPayment is not a function
```

my code is pls what i am doing wrong

```
stripe.customers.create(
            {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                phone: reqObj.phone,
                address: { "city": reqObj.address, "country": "IN",
     "line1": "", "line2": "", "state":"India" },
            },
            function (err, customer) {
                if (err) {res.json({ "status": false, "error": err })
                    console.log(err)
                }else {
                customer_id=customer.id;
    stripe.tokens.create(
        {
            card: {
                number: reqObj.card_no,
                exp_month: reqObj.exp_month,
                exp_year: reqObj.exp_year,
                cvc: reqObj.cvc
            },
        },
        function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ "status": false, "errorT": err})
            } else {
                // stripe.customers.createSource(
                //     customer_id,
                //     { source: token.id },
                    // function (err, card) {
                        // if (err) {
                            // res.json({ status: "false", "error": err })
                        // }else {
                            stripe.plans.list(
                                { product: "prod_IMGu6PI2mJbBCi", active: true },
                                function (err, plans) {
                                    if (!err) {
                            for(i in plans.data){
                                if(plans.data[i].amount==reqObj.amount){
                                    var myId=plans.data[i].id
                   stripe.paymentMethods.create({
                        type: 'card',
                        card: {
                            number: reqObj.card_no,
                            exp_month: reqObj.exp_month,
                            exp_year: reqObj.exp_year,
                            cvc: reqObj.cvc
                        },
                        },function(err,result){
                        // console.log(err,result) 
                        stripe.paymentMethods.attach(result.id, {
                            customer: customer_id,
                          },function(err,result1){ 
                            //   console.log(err,"result1",result1)
                          stripe.customers.update(
                            customer_id,
                            {
                              invoice_settings: {
                                default_payment_method: result.id,
                              },
                            },function(err,res2){ 
                                // console.log(err,"res2")
                            stripe.subscriptions.create({
                                customer: customer_id,
                                items: [{ price: myId}],
                                expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
                              },function(err,res3){ 
                                  console.log(err,"res3",
    res3.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret)
                          a=res3.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret
                      stripe.confirmCardPayment(
    res3.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret,
    function(err,paymentIntent)
                        {
                            console.log(err,"paymentIntent",paymentIntent)
                        }
                            )}
                              );
                            } );
                        });
                    });

                    
            }
        });
                }
                // asynchronously called
            });
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: @BhavinThummar pls check koopajah answer below 
for me i did it by using git sdk for 3d sedcure payment method

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mixing up client-side and server-side code together which will not work. The `stripe.confirmCardPayment()` method comes from Stripe.js and should be called client-side in Javascript inside the browser, not server-side with Node.js.

The beginning of your code is updating a Customer with the right default payment method id. Then it's creating a Subscription. And then, if the creation fails to have the first invoice paid, for example if the card is declined or requires 3D Secure, you have to then go back to the client, in the browser, to run the next step which is to confirm the PaymentIntent associated with the Subscription's Invoice.

So you need to go back to the client, where you originally created the PaymentMethod id `pm_123456` that you passed in `result.id` and then try to confirm the PaymentIntent.

Comment: is there an alternate method to verify payment on the backend with clientSecret or other?

Comment: got what I needed with a combination of metadata in payment intent and [list all charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list)